# Stripping trailing or leading characters in NSString

Tags: objective-c

Given the following strings:

```
s1 = '000001234'
s2 = '123400'
```

How would I strip off the trailing and leading zeros?

In python I can do:

```
s1 = s1.lstrip('0') # 1234
s2 = s2.rstrip('0') # 1234
s1, s2 = s1.strip('0'), s2.strip('0') # 1234, 1234
```

How would I do the equivalent in Objective-C given the two strings above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various possible solutions, here is one using regular expressions.
(`NSScanner` would be an alternative).

```
NSString *s1 = @"000120340";
NSString *t1 = [s1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"^0*" withString:@""
        options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s1 length])];
NSLog(@"%@", t1); // "120340"

NSString *s2 = @"012034000";
NSString *t2 = [s2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"0*$" withString:@""
        options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [s2 length])];
NSLog(@"%@", t2); // "012034"
```

Removing the zeros from *both* ends of the string simultaneously
is called "trimming" and can be done with

```
NSString *s3 = @"00012034000";
NSCharacterSet *zeroCharset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0"];
NSString *t3 = [s3 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:zeroCharset];
NSLog(@"%@", t3); // "12034"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler and cleaner solution:

```
    NSString *s1 = @"0001234";
    NSString *s2 = @"123400000";

    while ([[s1 substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"0"]) 
        s1 = [s1 substringFromIndex:1];

    while ([[s2 substringFromIndex:[s2 length]-1] isEqualToString:@"0"]) 
       s2 = [s2 substringToIndex:[s2 length]-1];

    NSLog(@"s1: %@", s1);
    NSLog(@"s2: %@", s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution: Numbers themselves do not have leading zeros (but of cause trailing), so to get of the leading zeros we just need to convert them to number objects and then back to strings. This will remove them. But that doesn't work for trailing zeros.

```
NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *leftStripped = [f stringFromNumber:[f numberFromString:self]];
```

But we can make it work, we just reverse the string, than create a number of it, create a string from that and reverse that again.

so first strip the left zeros

```
NSString *leftStripped = [f stringFromNumber:[f numberFromString:aNumberString]];
```

than reverse it

```
NSMutableString *reversedLeftStripped = [@"" mutableCopy];

[leftStripped enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0,[leftStripped length])
                                 options:(NSStringEnumerationReverse | NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences)
                              usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                                  [reversedLeftStripped appendString:substring];
                              }];
```

create a number object of that and a string from the number

```
NSString *rightLeftStrippedReversed = [f stringFromNumber:[f numberFromString:reversedLeftStripped]];
```

and reverse it

```
NSMutableString *rightLeftStripped = [@"" mutableCopy];

[rightLeftStrippedReversed enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [rightLeftStrippedReversed length]) options:NSStringEnumerationReverse| NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    [rightLeftStripped appendString:substring];
}];
```

I would use a category for that:

```
@interface NSString (Stripping)

-(NSString *)stringByStrippingLeadingAndTrailingZeros;

@end

@implementation NSString (Stripping)

-(NSString *)stringByStrippingLeadingAndTrailingZeros
{
    static NSNumberFormatter *f;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    });

    NSString *leftStripped = [f stringFromNumber:[f numberFromString:self]];
    NSMutableString *reversedLeftStripped = [@"" mutableCopy];

    [leftStripped enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0,[leftStripped length])
                                     options:(NSStringEnumerationReverse | NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences)
                                  usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                                      [reversedLeftStripped appendString:substring];
                                  }];

    NSString *rightLeftStrippedReversed = [f stringFromNumber:[f numberFromString:reversedLeftStripped]];
    NSMutableString *rightLeftStripped = [@"" mutableCopy];

    [rightLeftStrippedReversed enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [rightLeftStrippedReversed length]) options:NSStringEnumerationReverse| NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
        [rightLeftStripped appendString:substring];
    }];

    return rightLeftStripped;
}

@end
```

so you can easily call

```
NSString *s1 = @"0001234";
NSString *s2 = @"123400000";

for (NSString *string in @[s1, s2]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [string stringByStrippingLeadingAndTrailingZeros]);
}
```

In production code I would create a helper method to reverse the strings.